# Compiler behavior regarding class objects I don't understand

Tags: c++, class, compiler-construction, constructor, destructor

I'm a noob and still learning the c++ language. The thing is, doing an exercise from a book, I've come across a compiler behavior I don't understand.

The header file.

```
// stock10.h -- Stock class declaration with constructors, destructor added

#ifndef STOCK10_H_
#define STOCK10_H_

#include <string>

class Stock
{
private:
    std::string company;
    long shares;
    double share_val;
    double total_val;
    void set_tot() { total_val = shares * share_val; }
public:
    // two constructors
    Stock(); // default constructor
    Stock(const std::string & co, long n = 0, double pr = 0.0);
    ~Stock(); // noisy destructor
    void buy(long num, double price);
    void sell(long num, double price);
    void update(double price);
    void show();
};

#endif
```

The class implementation.

```
// stock10.cpp -- Stock class with constructors, destructor added

#include <iostream>
#include "stock10.h"

// constructors (verbose versions)
Stock::Stock() // default constructor
{
    std::cout << "Default constructor called\n";
    company = "no name";
    shares = 0;
    share_val = 0.0;
    total_val = 0.0;
}

Stock::Stock(const std::string & co, long n, double pr)
{
    std::cout << "Constructor using " << co << " called\n";
    company = co;
    if (n < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Number of shares can’t be negative; "
                  << company << " shares set to 0.\n";
        shares = 0;
    }
    else
        shares = n;
    share_val = pr;
    set_tot();
}

// class destructor
Stock::~Stock() // verbose class destructor
{
    std::cout << "Bye, " << company << "!\n";
}

// other methods
void Stock::buy(long num, double price)
{
    if (num < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Number of shares purchased can’t be negative. "
                  << "Transaction is aborted.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        shares += num;
        share_val = price;
        set_tot();
    }
}

void Stock::sell(long num, double price)
{
    using std::cout;
    if (num < 0)
    {
        cout << "Number of shares sold can’t be negative. "
             << "Transaction is aborted.\n";
    }
    else if (num > shares)
    {
        cout << "You can’t sell more than you have! "
             << "Transaction is aborted.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        shares -= num;
        share_val = price;
        set_tot();
    }
}

void Stock::update(double price)
{
    share_val = price;
    set_tot();
}

void Stock::show()
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::ios_base;
    // set format to #.###
    ios_base::fmtflags orig =
        cout.setf(ios_base::fixed, ios_base::floatfield);
    std::streamsize prec = cout.precision(3);
    cout << "Company: " << company
         << " Shares: " << shares << '\n';
    cout << " Share Price: $" << share_val;
    // set format to #.##
    cout.precision(2);
    cout << " Total Worth: $" << total_val << '\n';
    // restore original format
    cout.setf(orig, ios_base::floatfield);
    cout.precision(prec);
}
```

The main file.

```
// usestok1.cpp -- using the Stock class
// compile with stock10.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "stock10.h"

int main()
{
    {
        using std::cout;
        cout << "Using (non default) constructors to create new objects\n";
        Stock stock1("NanoSmart", 12, 20.0); // syntax 1
        stock1.show();
        Stock stock2 = Stock ("Boffo Objects", 2, 2.0); // syntax 2
        stock2.show();

        cout << "Assigning stock1 to stock2:\n";
        stock2 = stock1;
        cout << "Listing stock1 and stock2:\n";
        stock1.show();
        stock2.show();

        cout << "Using a constructor to reset an object\n";
        stock1 = Stock("Nifty Foods", 10, 50.0); // temp object
        cout << "Revised stock1:\n";
        stock1.show();
        cout << "Done\n";
    }
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

As you may have guessed, Stock is the class and I've created non-default constructor and destructor to display messages to see when they "act".

Here's the output from program execution:

> Using (non default) constructors to create new objects
>   Constructor using NanoSmart called
>   Company: NanoSmart Shares: 12
>    Share Price: $20.000 Total Worth: $240.00
>   Constructor using Boffo Objects called
>   Company: Boffo Objects Shares: 2
>    Share Price: $2.000 Total Worth: $4.00
>   Assigning stock1 to stock2:
>   Listing stock1 and stock2:
>   Company NanoSmart Shares: 12
>    Share Price: $20.000 Total Worth: $240.00
>   Company NanoSmart Shares: 12
>    Share Price: $20.000 Total Worth: $240.00
>   Using a constructor to reset an object
>   Constructor using Nifty Foods called
>   **Bye, NanoSmart!** // *Why? Shouldn't it be Bye, Nifty Foods?*
>   Revised stock1:
>   Company: Nifty Foods Shares: 10
>    Share Price: $50.000 Total Worth: $500.00
>   Done
>   Bye, NanoSmart!
>   Bye, Nifty Foods!

In this specific line:

```
stock1 = Stock("Nifty Foods", 10, 50.0); // temp object
```

Shouldn't the compiler:
1. Create a temporary object with the constructor
2. Assign that object to the stock1 object
3. Destroy the temporary object

Shouldn't the message say Nifty Foods instead of NanoSmart?

I don't get it. Any help?

Comment: You better show us your class before we could possible answer your question. At least the class declaration, copy-constructor and assignment operator (if you implemented one, which you probably should otherwise).

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg sorry for that. I added the class implementation file.

Comment: Could you please add the header file as well? We might need to see how you declare the class member variables as well.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your output. I get `Bye, Nifty foods!`.

Comment: The output doesn't match; `"Assigning stock1 to stock2:\n"` isn't shown.  Please post the actual output.

Comment: See here http://ideone.com/pGyM4

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @ecatmur: The behavior could be explained by a compiler doing the wrong thing: *moving*. That would explain the lack of *copy* but existence of destructor call and the fact that the destructor is printing the message previously stored in the `stock1` object.

Comment: The output still doesn't match the program; where's the `"Assigning stock1 to stock2:\n"` line?

Comment: Downvoting until the actual output corresponding to the program is supplied.

Comment: @ecatmur sorry for that. copied by hand from the console. I already corrected it. Thanks for your help. It has to be a compiler bug.

Comment: Retracted downvote.  Looks like a compiler bug, indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a assignment operator defined, so if you are using a C++11 compiler, it probably uses the move assignment operator, which swaps the objects and then deletes the new contents of the temp object, which used to be in `stock1`.

At least, that is the observed behavior. ecatmur is correct, however, that your class should not have received an implicit move assignment operator. That might of course be a compiler bug.

Comment: But I'm not creating the object. It's already created. in your example is bar = Foo(something). bar is already created

Comment: @Kurospidey When you do `stock1 = Stock("Nifty Foods", 10, 50.0);`, the compiler will create a temporary object, then use the assignment operator of `stock1`to copy the temporary object. If you don't have your own assignment operator then the one generated by the compiler may do the wrong things.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg that i understand. but after that, shouldn't it destroy that temporary object? so the message should be "Bye, Nifty Foods" cause it's destroying the object with the company name Nifty Foods. Instead it says "Bye, NanoSmart" like if it were destroying the stock1 object, which it shouldn't

Comment: Sorry, I meant the assignment operators. Same thing, though. Note that after using the move assignment operator, the temp object may very well hold the contents that `stock1` used to have.

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig the move assignment operator is suppressed per 12.8:20 by the user-declared destructor.

Comment: @Kurospidey: This is a new feature in C++11: *move semantics*. And it seems that your particular compiler is implementing *move semantics* for a string as a swap of the old and new string. Consider the C++03 version of your code: a new object is created ("Nifty"), and it is assigned to `stock1`. `stock1` releases it's internal `std::string` ("Nano"), then copies the new one ("Nifty"). At this point there are two strings holding the same data: "Nifty" and one string was released. At the end of the expression, the destructor for the temporary is executed, releasing "Nifty"...

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig Thanks for that answer. So the book author explained it poorly. Maybe in his compiler it worked accordingly without introducing that matter yet, but in mine it won't.

Comment: ... now, that requires an allocation and a copy of the string. But the compiler knows that the string inside the temporary is going to be released immediately, so it can do better: instead of copying the string from the temporary, it can swap the contents (cheap operation), and let the temporary destroy the old contents previously inside `stock1`. This removes one allocation and a copy that might be expensive. **Disclaimer**: This is an explanation of what move semantics are, but the compiler should not have applied them here.

Comment: @Kurospidey: Most books on the shelves (including good ones) have been written before the new standard was approved, which means that if you use a C++11 compiler in C++11 mode (in VS you cannot disable this) then you might see some behavioral differences. In this particular case the compiler seems to be wrong though (*What compiler are you running?*)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I'm a total noob, so I downloaded a special version of mingw so i could run the binaries from any directory without other files dependencies. I suppose it mixes all in the exes cause they're heavy.

Comment: @Kurospidey: If you are compiling with mingw you are probably running `g++`, try `g++ --version` to see the compiler version. Also, depending on how it was configured, it might be running in C++11 mode by default.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas mingw32-g++ (tdm-1) 4.6.1 but I'm running it from codeblocks with c++ 11 activated

Comment: @Kurospidey: I would suggest that you disable C++11 if you are following a text book (more so since C++11 support in compilers is not really stable). Then, after you understand the behavior of your program, you can switch to C++11 and compile the same thing, if you notice a change in behavior... beware, the change of the standard should not cause visible side effects!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't written a copy assignment operator `Stock::operator=(const Stock &)` or move assignment operator `Stock::operator=(Stock &&)`, so your assignment `stock1 = Stock("Nifty Foods", 10, 50.0);` will invoke an implicitly defined copy/move assignment operator:

> [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)
>
> #### 12.8 Copying and moving class objects [class.copy]
>
> 18 - If the class deﬁnition does not explicitly declare a copy assignment operator, one is declared implicitly. If
>   the class deﬁnition declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the implicitly declared copy
>   assignment operator is deﬁned as deleted; otherwise, it is deﬁned as defaulted (8.4).
>   28 - The implicitly-deﬁned copy/move assignment operator for a non-union class X performs memberwise copy-
>   /move assignment of its subobjects.

Because your class has a user-defined destructor, the move assignment operator will not be implicitly defined (12.8:20), so the implicitly defined copy assignment operator will be called:

> 20 - If the deﬁnition of a class X does not explicitly declare a move assignment operator, one will be implicitly
>   declared as defaulted if and only if [...]
>
> > - X does not have a user-declared destructor

Thus the `Stock("Nifty Foods", 10, 50.0)` will be memberwise copied into `stock1` and then destructed; so the message displayed will be `"Bye, Nifty Foods!"`.

Here's a SSCCE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
struct S {
    std::string s;
    S(const std::string &s): s(s) { std::cout << "S(" << s << ")\n"; }
    ~S() { std::cout << "~S(" << s << ")\n"; }
};
int main() {
    S a("a");
    a = S("b");
}
```

Output:

```
S(a)
S(b)
~S(b)
~S(b)
```

Comment: The question is, why isn't that message displayed. OP claims `Bye, NanoSmart!` is printed.

Comment: @juanchopanza OP is incorrect or is using a non-conformant implementation.

Comment: It looks like it. I haven't been able to reproduce it on a variety of GCCs.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. I'm using mingw (probably a strange version)

Answer (score -1):

I don't see anything immediately wrong with your code, but you should probably implement a copy-constructor and assignment operator anyway, just to be sure that copying is performed correctly.

something like this:

```
class Stock
{
    // ...

public:
    // ...

    Stock(const Stock &other)
        : company(other.company), shares(other.shares),
          share_val(other.share_val), total_val(other.total_val)
        { }

    Stock &operator=(const Stock &other)
        {
            company   = other.company;
            shares    = other.shares;
            share_val = other.share_val;
            total_val = other.total_val;

            return *this;
        }

    // ...
};
```

For more information about copy-constructors, see e.g. [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor). For the assignment operator, see e.g. [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_operator_in_C%2B%2B).

Comment: A copy constructor/assignment that just does what the default one would do is redundant and a potential source for errors.  You usually don't need them if the class doesn't have pointer members.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is I'm following a book while learning the language. And in this particular exercise the author claims the program output should be that one with the tools I'm using right now. I think it should be that one also, but the compiler thinks otherwise, and I don't know why.

Comment: @ibid In this case the compiler defaults obviously does something wrong, or the OP wouldn't have posted the question.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, did you try the OP's code?  Did you reproduce the OP's anomalous result, and did your suggestion fix it for you?  For me, the OP's code works correctly with no changes.